# Error while compiling typescript in VSCode

Tags: typescript, target, iterable

I have the following code which I am trying to compile:

```
function twoSum(nums: number[], target: number): number[] {
    let res:number[] = [];
    let dict = new Map<number, number>();
    for (let [index, value] of nums.entries()) {
        if (dict.has(target - value)) {
            let current = dict.get(target - value)!;
            res.push(current);
            res.push(index);
            break;
        }

        dict.set(value, index);
    }
    return res;
};
```

But I get the following error:

```
test.ts:4:32 - error TS2802: Type 'IterableIterator<[number, number]>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher.

4     for (let [index, value] of nums.entries()) {
```

I am using tsc to compile. I have already updated tsconfig.json like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */


    "include": [     "test.ts",     "src/**/*"   ], 
    "downlevelIteration": true,   
    "target": "es2023",                                  
    "lib": ["es2023"],
```

Can anybody please help?

Just want to compile and run  the code. I am learning typescript using VSCode.